# How to scroll QChart

Tags: qt, plot, charts, scroll, qchart

I am creating a plotting application with QCharts.

I have realtime data, so I need to periodically update the chart.
I use QCharts::scroll function, but it does not seem to be working.
For example `scroll(100.0, 0)` shifts only 0.84 on the x-axis.

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is documentation for the method: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#scroll

Thank you very much

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your code -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: I wanted to, it is quite complex. I will try, but it is possible I have solved the problem in the meantime.

Comment: Yeah, solved ow. Thank you very much.